# Не работает javascript. Помогите разобраться, может неправильно подключил?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html> 
  <head>
    <title> How 2-group member you are </title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="image/favicon.png" type="image/png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_test.css" type="text/css">
    <script>
        start() {
            alert('Hello');
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="start()">
    <h1 id="name">What is the motto of 2-group before tests?</h1>
    <main>
        <table class="table">
            <tr >
              <td><button onclick="first()" id="first">За Марий-Эл</button></td>
              <td><h3 onclick="second()" id="second">За 2 группу</h3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
              <td><h3 onclick="third()" id="third">За Путина</h3></td>
              <td><h3 onclick="fourth()" id="fourth">За Инфотех</h3></td>
            </tr>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Еще у вас тег `table` не закрыт в HTML-разметке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="script_test.js"></script>
// или файл, или код внутри тэга
<script>
    function start() {
        alert('Hello');
    }
</script>
```

Обратите также внимание на слово `function` перед словом `start`.

Comment: Поправил, там у меня ни так, ни так не работает.

Comment: @DenisSakhno Обратите также внимание на слово `function` перед словом `start`.